# A way to determine a symmetric connector's position

Tags: connector

I have an old, custom pair of connectors in use by what will be a large number of systems. The connectors are mother/father and symmetrical, as in they don't have a mechanical guide to have the user plug it in in the "right" position.

I cannot alter the father device and connector in any way.

[image: father connector (this is what the users plug in)]

The 4 pins are: VCC GND Rx Tx. I have a high voltage on the power pin and Rx/Tx logic is at 5V. Rx/Tx clock is pre-set at a particular value.

[image: mother connector pinout]

Therefore, the father connector can be plugged in in 4 possible ways.

Mother supplies father with VCC under 1000V and under 100A if and when the pins are "aligned". Until then, the devices can talk through Rx and Tx @ 5V (there is a small rechargeable battery on the father connector end device).

Connectors' and devices' case(s) are non-conductive.

I need to be able to detect the orientation / how the father connector is inserted so I can relay current and signals properly, so that the devices will connect and talk regardless how the connectors are plugged in.

What is the best way to accomplish this? By "best way" I mean least number of components/FETs/relays/diodes. I can use any type of MCU on my end, was looking at a L0-class from STM.

NB: an electro-mechanical device behind the mother connector, in the form of a disk is rotated by a motor in steps of 90' clockwise (basically up to 4 "tries" are made until the signals are properly aligned) has been proposed through another channel, I am not looking for this kind of solution, need something solid state, without moving parts.

Comment: It would be much simpler to make a protection circuit that ensures nothing burns when it is plugged wrong, but it won't work until plugged right. Also, considering "VCC" and "GND" can be swapped, and "GND" might end up connected to the chassis, and "VCC" is "high voltage" 380V then this is a "kill yourself if you plug it wrong" kind of connector... not really something I'd want to touch...

Comment: I cant think of any solution that wont cost you more than throwing those connectors away and buying new, keyed, connectors or housings.

Comment: The point is for the connection to work regardless how it's plugged in, although I do admit it would be "easier" to turn on a warning sign if improperly connected. I can't buy new connectors, must use these, regardless of cost (certifications involved). Will accept the answer that solves the problem with least number of additional components.

Comment: What about the "kill yourself" bit?

Comment: Circuit open until I know which pin to connect to VCC, after determining orientation.

Comment: SO you would need something at both ends....?

Comment: How much current draw from VCC? Is VCC AC or DC and can you confirm 380V?

Comment: HOw much V is Vcc?

Comment: Only on mother connector end (which is where the power supply is). I can't mess with the father end of the appliance. All I can do is attempt to establish a connection on Rx/Tx pins by rotation. Current is high but under 1000V and 100A.

Comment: So all 4 wires can carry 20 amps? Is the circuit to be located on the power supply side, or on the other side? Can the other side be modified? ("mother" and "father" are confusing, which is the supply side?)

Comment: Circuit will be located on mother side which is where the power supply is. The other side cannot be modified.

Comment: Is there a metallic connector shell? Is it grounded? Does the cable have a shield which is connected to the connector's shell? Is one wire connected to the shell?

Comment: Connector shell is non-conductive, not connected. We only deal with and about those 4 pins.

Comment: OK, have you checked this will not break any safety standards (like the need for earthing, etc)? Also, on the "father" end, is the GND connected to Earth or to a metallic enclosure that people can touch?

Comment: Will the "father" end RX and TX respond to signals if VCC is absent? If not, you have a chicken and egg problem: can't send VCC without being sure it's the right pin or the device will fry, but can't talk to the device without VCC being applied...

Comment: Nothing is connected to any case or anything that can pose immediate safety risk. These are different matters though. My task is to find ways to align the signals. And yes, Rx/Tx will respond to signals without Vcc (there's a small rechargeable battery on the device) if and when pins properly aligned.

Comment: What is the impedance between Vcc and Gnd compared to the others

Comment: And does wither the TX or Rx pin have a voltage on it vs GND when it is unplugged.

Comment: Unsure about impedance at this time, I would say around 50-100mO on VCC off the top of my head. Rx/Tx are at up at 5V initially, it's some type of synchronous serial connection.

Comment: One or Rx Tx is an input though right... One at 5V output the other floating input?

Comment: BTW: You have another issue you have not mentioned. You need to be able to detect when it is unplugged too, so some idiot does not unplug it when powered on and rotate it and plug it back in.

Comment: When plug is pulled (serial communication times out) I guess I can switch off the power supply and reassess orientation when plugged in again. They can't possibly plug it out and back in within a few clock ticks I'd need to detect a timeout, we're talking about a 2Mhz clock on the serial connection. In fact in theory I can even add some way to detect the noise generated by the friction between pins and switch off before they even plug it out, but this is taking it too far. There are ways, but this isn't my main concern. Right now I am trying to determine the best way to align signals.

Comment: OK, so if the "father" end holds its TX at 5V and is battery powered, then you can identify which pin is TX. Unless RX also has a pullup which holds it at 5V... So, what voltages does the father device output on each pin when VCC is absent?

Comment: You say this can't be changed because of certifications, but honestly any "certification" which allowed this connector to be used for 1000 V is worth less than zero.  I would walk away. This isn't worth dying over, and any solution to this is going to be intrinsically risky.  There is basically no way you can *prove* that the microcontroller (or whatever) can't hang and leave the power in a dangerous state.

Comment: @NickM: (1) Nobody has asked, but what exactly is the device? (2) Why would it have been designed without a polarised connector? (3) What is the serial protocol? (4) Can you elaborate on how TX / RX are referenced to GND? (5) You should condense all the points raised here back into your question.

Comment: It's a power supply connector for an old type of underwater ROV used by a certain government's contractors in some prospecting projects. It was designed some 15-20 years ago and has not yet reached its EOL. As with most government projects the design lacks in many aspects and is quite troublesome to work with. See how the US military spends $2000 on a $.05 MCU used in missile guidance systems simply because the original designer has got the certifications in place and nobody is willing to spend that much to sell today's MCUs for such programs because the certifications make it unfeasible.

Comment: Of course. High voltage, salt water, and stupid regulations had to be involved, all at the same time. Especially salt water. For the record, I will state that this is a bad idea, in case someone gets electrocuted.

Comment: Bad idea or not I have to come up with something safer and more feasible. Fortunately they're not charging the robot battery when underwater...possibly because they can't hook it up with the winch to lift it and launch it when connected to the power line.

Comment: Forgive my innocence, but could this not be avoided simply by applying a dab of brightly colored paint on the VCC side of both the plug and socket and instructing all operators to use those marks for alignment?  Military techs tend to be pretty good at following instructions like that.  And obviously you'd need some sort of paint that won't come off in salt water, but such things exist.  Or would even paint qualify as "altering" the plugs?

Comment: They've tried it in the past and it didn't work out too well. They even tried making some dents in the connectors, using sticky labels and whatnot. I wish it was that easy.

Answer (score 4):

Since the thing you are plugging in is pushing out a voltage relative to the ground pin on the Tx line (and maybe a pullup on the Rx) you ought to be able to use a circuit like the one below as a start.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb3ZaB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pull each pin to ground one at a time and examine which other pins are driving back. You ought to be able to figure out which pin is the actual ground pin that way. Once you know that, switch in the TX/RX signals to the correct pins (not shown) and verify communication before turning on the appropriate power P-MOSFET.

Once you know which one is ground, and have it powered up, detecting the plug getting pulled should simply be a matter of monitoring the transistor on the Vcc line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a circuit similar to two-stage [barrel shifter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter) to allow rotating the signals by 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8w3GZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use either solid state or mechanical relays for the switches. There are only two control signals, allowing 4 possible settings corresponding to the 4 possible orientations.

To find the correct orientation, just toggle through the settings until you get a valid RX/TX signal. Because the high-voltage supply is not enabled before you find the correct orientation, the logic only has to handle +- 5V on the rx/tx signals. A simple series resistor and diode clamp could be sufficient.

(Of course it would be smart to have some kind of fall-back protection in case the high voltage does end up on the wrong pins, but that's enough of a topic for another question.)