Advice on making a quad-directional power/data connector
I have an interesting problem that I'd like some input on. It's a bit complex, so I'll do my best to explain it clearly.
I have a connector with 4 pins arranged in a square pattern. The pins are designated as +, -, D1, and D2 (where D1/D2 is I2C). The challenge is that the solution must work regardless of the connector's orientation when it is plugged in (i.e., it must be position-agnostic).

I know this is a easy fix by just using a correct plug, but this is
not what I'm asking. Question isn't really about the plug, but how to
solve the problem for the plug I'm describing below.

Layout of pins can be changed to whatever could best solve the problem.
Here is a visualisation of the connection I have so far:

I have to make it so that no matter what way I attach a plug it will work.
I can use a microcontroller and anything else I wan't.
I came up with a solution, but would like to see if I can get some better ideas or improvements.
If I add a bridge in this configuration I will get power no matter what direction the plug has connected:

Next I would cut the signal for A or B lines using P-MOSFET and note in my microcontroller memory what line I am cutting:

If my microcontroller is still working after a few milliseconds, it means it has correctly identified the power and data pairs. It then triggers switches to route the data lines appropriately. If it guessed wrong and cuts off the power pair, the system will reset, turning off the microcontroller and MOSFETs. On reset, the microcontroller will try again with the opposite pair, remembering the last state it tried.
Here is a quick sketch of the configuration I imagine:


On a side note here is my first iteration I came up with that had 4 pins in a line. Left side is signal source and right side is slave device:

While this works it has some issues, and is not ideal because of some other constraints that I don't wan't to go into. Ideally I wan't to solve this for the 4 corner configuration.
Another thought was adding clock and data to the power rail with some opamp magic and then decoding it on the other side. But it probably is a lot more complicated than I imagine, considering noise, power draw etc.

What are the "signals"? Digital/Analog? Are they the same voltage as the power supply? push-pull/open-drain/etc? Are they frequently changing, or can they sit at a certain voltage level for extended periods (and if so how long)? Can you change this (i.e. is the external device off-the-shelf, or are you making both ends)?

I'm making both ends of the device. The signals are I2C. I have protections on both ends for cases when power is fed in to them. And they are flipped at the source end to adjust the data/clock lines so they match what the slave needs.

In your solution you have a voltage drop of two body diodes and two normal diodes which sums up to around 2.4 - 2.8 V difference between the external supply and the MCU. Is this acceptable?

Yes. Im using diodes with low voltage drop. So it is around 1v. But even 2-3 would be fine.

If you're making both ends of the device, why the restriction that you can't use any plug you like?

What is the intended supply voltage range at the connector? Your suggested circuit has no VSS return path to the connector and some other issues, e.g. shortcut between two inputs if the PFET pair turns on.

Are the four pins fixed in a square or do you have the ability to place them slightly off ?

@Hearth this isn't exactly a plug, think of it more of UI. But the constraint is not important.

@Jens it would be around 5V. You are right about the return path, I missed that. But it's a easy fix. Not sure about the last point you made, could you show where is the shortcut.

@Criggie they can be arranged in a different configuration if that helps with the solution. Originally I had 6 pins that I figured out, but I'm trying to get down to 4.

@Jens I might have been wrong with return path "easy fix". Can't get around it at the moment.

@somerandomusername It would be helpful if you can fully explain why this constraint is there. Otherwise, it's hard not to want to just say that you're using the wrong plug for the job.

@Hearth It is not a plug. More of a machine to machine interface. Imagine how you would interface a phone/handwatch with a wireless charger. You just put the device on it without plugging anything not worrying about the orientation. The thing I'm prototyping has a similar "feeling", just not wireless. It has magnets to lock on, but there must be no restriction for orientation.

It's a pity you're using I2C and not 1-wire (I assume the latter is too slow) because then you ought to be able to get down to 2 pins (or really easily, 3 in a row, or cross if you need to support 90° positions).  I wonder if relaxing the conditions to 5 pins with a ground in the middle of the square might help - a fixed reference normally makes things easier and should reduce the number of series diodes

@ChrisH I considered 1-wire, but as you say it was too slow. Speed is somewhat important for this project.

Similar question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334417/a-way-to-determine-a-symmetric-connectors-position

@jpa The major difference is that here we have the MCU getting power over the rotatable connector (so the power part of the circuit needs to work without any help from the MCU), and there we have the MCU deciding which pin of the rotatable connector should be used to power the other end; this requires a completely different circuit.

Why wouldn't you just use a keyed plug that can't be plugged in the wrong way?

@MPW trust me that it won't fit the project. If it was just about the plug I would do so. This question is about solving the problem with a circuit not a plug.

I think this works, but I haven't simulated or tested it.

Here's what's going on: The mating connector must have power in the two corner pins, and I2C in the other two corner pins.
There are two bridges (with their outputs coupled together) to provide power to the MCU, and all four pins have pull up resistors connected to the bridge output positive. The MCU needs to have two I2C ports. You might need to add a voltage regulator to the power lines before the MCU.
Let's look at an example of it in use:

Here we've connected +ve power to the top right (red) and ground to the bottom left (black). I2C are the green pins.
The active I2C lines in this case are the orange ones.
If you were to use a PSoC microcontroller from Infineon to implement the I2C swapping, you'd need to implement a circuit inside it to perform the swap at run time (it's not a function already provided by the I2C component). This design uses two pairs of external pins, which would need to be connected together on the PCB (blue dashed lines). There's also a way to do it by reprogramming the configuration registers, but that would need some digging into the technical reference manual.

They're pretty low cost devices, but may not be cheap enough for your application.

Oh. This definitely looks promising. I have only one I2C hardware interface on the IC I'm using. But I can route multiple pins to it internally. Will play around with this and see how it goes. I have a bunch of free pins to try and "listen" on each of the 4 corners to "see" the orientation and select appropriate I2C pins - without waiting on data from them.

I put it in a simple online falstad simulator and it seems to work as you described. I will try to breadboard this soon and see how it goes.

@somerandomusername - Nice. I hope it works. I'd love to know what the project is.

I will let you know how the tests went. And some time in the future I will do a writeup on the project if it actually turns out as I imagine. Will keep you posted.

Note that this is actually the same as the answer by @2012rcampion, just drawn differently.

Also the viability of this solution depends on the particular MCU — e.g., STM32 won't be able to cope with swapped SDA and SCL, which would happen when the plug is rotated by 180°; so you may still end up needing some external mux chips, or maybe find 4 pairs of I2C-supporting pins to cover all possible orientations (so that each pin of the connector will have two MCU pins connected — one with the SDA function, another with SCL).

@SergeyVlasov - That's a good point. I can highly recommend the PSoC chips from Infineon. They would allow you to re-configure the pinout at runtime. The MCU could try every combination of pinouts to see what works. Alternatively, if this is the master, than bit banging is easily reconfigurable.

@Rocketmagnet Can you point me to some PSoC chip that actually supports swapping SDA and SCL? I randomly picked CY8C6144LQI-S4F12 and CYS0644ABZI-S2D44T, and it looks like they have usual alternate function tables for pins which have some specific pins with the SDA and SCL functions, with no way to swap them.

Good points here. The "master" device has software I2C, so I can swap wires to test what the slave needs, I already tested this and it works well. The slave device supports multiple pins as I2C inputs, haven't tested it, but it seems so at the first glance. It is the CH32v003x familly.

@Rocketmagnet so I put it together on a breadboard and it works exactly as described. This is a amazing solution, and easy/cheap component wise. Thank you.

@SergeyVlasov - Any of the CY8C42 or CY8C5 families should be able to do this. It's not a trivial function of the I2C component in the device, you'd need to wire up a circuit inside the device to handle the swapping.

Instead of four discrete pins, use a 4-circuit circularly-symmetrical connector.
These connectors may be plugged-in in any orientation. Regardless of orientation, each contact is connected to the corresponding contact in the mate. There is no need to detect the orientation and reroute the signals.

In-line:


Helicopter headphone (top left)




3.5 mm TRRS phone (middle left)


Coplanar:


Concentric coplanar cylindrical (top right)




Flush concentric (bottom right)




{Sources: Digikey, Digikey, LEMO, Fischer}

Thank you for your input. I probably should have made it clearer that I'm really not asking this as a solution for the plug. But as a signal/pin detection problem. For reasons I won't go into I need to solve it for the plug that I described.

You can also consider moving almost all inteligence into master - put current-limited H-bridge + i2c on each leg. On slave, put protection diodes on scl and sda (against + and - leg) and antiparallel diode between + and -. Master can probe (single) combination that is shorted by diode, then reverse polarity and communicate normally.

Is it a strict requirement that your I2C and power are run on separate sets of pins?  If not, you can add a chip like the MAX20340 that will let you send and receive data over your DC power line, which makes your connector orientation issue significantly easier to solve (your original bridge circuit might be sufficient).

Yes I did consider using I2C over power line. But when I looked into it all the IC's where quite pricey. Wouldn't be a problem for one off device. But I will potentially need couple of hundred of these "connectors". So put together with other components it wouldn't scale well.

To put it in perspective all the parts+pcb for one of them would be around 1USD, so this kind of MAX20340 would double or triple that.

@somerandomusername That was just the first example I could find, others exist that may be cheaper.  Also, don't forget to factor in your time.  Spending 15 hours of engineering time trying to design something custom would likely cost more than spending $300 on additional parts.

The correct answer is to use a stout plug that has survived for decades of use and costs a few cents.
Designing your own connector is expensive and error prone.  However as an exercise, avoid a circuit-based solution and use geometry?
This assumes you have some lee-way to move the pins a little.  If they're fixed in a square, this solution won't work.
One side : viewed from above.  Each pin can land in any of 4 positions, which are simply pads on the same track and are joined together.
+-------------+
| - D2   D1 - |
|D1 +     + D2|
|             |
|             |
|D2 +     + D1|
| - D1   D2 - |
+-------------+

Other side:  (for simplicity, this is viewed from above also, so mirrored or "through")
+-------------+
| . .     . . |
| . +     . D2|
|             |
|             |
| . .     . . |
| . D1    . - |
+-------------+


Sorry. You assume that this is about the connector. But it isn't. Imagine that there are some dark forces that prevent me to do anything to the connector. This question is about the problem that I described, not the connector.
